# The procedure entry point getTimeout could not be located in the dll

Tags: windows-10, dll

I want to use [The Open Racing Car Simulator 1.3.7 (C/C++ project)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/torcs/) with python (I have Python 3.6.7 installed, removed other python versions). I was able to install the application and the [patch 2.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cig/files/SCR%20Championship/Server%20Windows/) (contains xml, rbg, makefile, sh, dll files) for the server.

Now I am getting the following errors[image]

```
operties Report
------------------------
Compatibility mode, properties unknown.
windowsModInfoDir: ...  can't open dll drivers/./..dll
windowsModInfoDir: ...  can't open dll drivers/../...dll
windowsModInfoDir: ...  can't open dll drivers/scr_server/scr_server.dll
windowsModInfoDir: ...  can't open dll drivers/sparkle/sparkle.dll
```

**EDIT: What I have tried**

- I tried reinstallation (Torcs 1.3.7 and Torcs 1.3.4) with and without the patch (version 1 and 2)
- cmd (as Admin) and `sfc /scannow`
- cmd (as Admin) and `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`
- Only application without patch (does work)
- Application with patch version 1 and version 2 (both raise the same error)
- .net framework 4.7.2 is allready installed
- The patch (for server) is for windows name is scr-win-patch.zip and was downloaded form the link which was provided in the official documentation for the windows installation of the server.
- The ~/drivers/scr_server/scr_server.dll file is there the
- The ~/drivers/sparkle/sparkle.dll file does not exist (and I cannot find it online). I just copied another driver *.dll and renamed it to sparkle the error message changed to -> can't find proc sparkle
- Dependency Walker output of scr_server (http://pasted.co/1d4b9c76)
- PATH variable

`%SystemRoot%\system32`
`%SystemRoot%`
`%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem`
`%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\`
`C:\Users\Cardano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36`
`C:\Users\Cardano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts`

But nothing did resolve the problem. I hope that someone will be able to help me with this problem.

Comment: What happens if you install it without patch 2.0 ?

Comment: SFC and DISM can only repair a system file if it exists in the image that was used to install Windows.  The files that are missing from your system cannot be repaired by either of those tools.  You can't repair a file that is missing entirely, and since they are third-party driver files, an integrity check is not even performed on them

Comment: Have you installed [.NET Framework 4.7.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework-runtime)?

Comment: @MrYouMath - You indicated that without the patch, the simulator works, but you get an error.  So is that a different error or the same error you are asking about.  Edit your question to clarify this fact.

Comment: @harrymc - TORCS has not seen a new release in years it's not even an .NET application.

Comment: @Ramhound: You may be right. It seems that getTimeout is also a Python function. In this case, the poster simply has a wrong Python version.

Comment: @harrymc - I believe it to be the case they don't even have Python installed.  Since the module cannot even be found, and the application won't even execute, a configuration error would be an error generated by the application.

Comment: @MrYouMath - "server does not work" does not provide enough information to submit an answer.

Comment: What Python version do you have installed?

Comment: @harrymc: Python 3.6.7 and Python 2.7.15

Comment: Which one is used by TORCS (and how do you know that)?

Comment: `getTimeout` is [documented in version 3.6](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/socket.html#socket.socket.gettimeout) as contained in `Lib/socket.py`. I don't know the Python setup enough to know if the Python `Lib` folder should be in your PATH or not for proper execution.

Comment: You probably need the Python version that was used to create TORCS. Finding it by date of the binaries is one way.

Comment: @MrYouMath - If you are not willing to update your question and provide all relevant and required information in the question body then I cannot help you.

Comment: I thought I saw TORCS was Python, but after I submitted that comment (with regards to it not being a .NET project), I couldn't find that statement again (which is the reason my comment now simply indicates it is NOT a .NET project).  At the end of the day, the files you are missing, are required to run the application and they do not exist in any of the locations Windows automatically looks at.  As for the information, I have asked for error messages, and you have (more than once), submitted a comment instead of providing the full error message in the body of the question.

Comment: So the error message in the question body, does not appear if the patch is not installed?  It only appears if the patch is installed.  If that is the case, it's the patch that is written in Python, not TORCS.  My comment still stands, you have submitted additional information in numerous comments, instead of modifying the question to include that information.  We now have information across several different comments, most of them are incomplete thoughts, due to the limitations of comments (hence the reason I have asked for clarification more then three times).

Comment: Verified, this is a C/C++ program. This is probably .Net Framework that is missing after all.

Comment: @Ramhound: No the error does not appearch without the patch. The patch is necessary to run Torcs as a server. After this error appears I cannot select the scr_server -> Cannot fire up server. The hint with the patch was interesting, but there are noe python files included in the patch. only xml and sh files. No python files are included. The patch only allows TORCS to run as a server. The client (python, C, C++, Java) can be selected by the user.

Comment: @harrymc:  .NET Framework 4.7.2 is installed.

Comment: Be sure to provide your PATH varaible.  Be sure to verify if the files in the error message even exist on your system.  Information from [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) will also be helpful.  Any additional and past infomration should be contained in the question body.  Allowing the comments to only contain requests for clarification (which will be deleted when they are no longer needed).

Comment: *.sh is typically a Linux Bash file extension. Are you poistive this patch is even meant for Windows?

Comment: One must have the correct version of the required file and it must be in a location Windows will search for it (the application directory is one of those locations).  Why wasn't your latest comment submitted as an edit to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86345/discussion-between-ramhound-and-mryoumath).