# How to delete an application without a trace in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dll

I have installed [The Open Simulation Race Car (TORCS)](https://superuser.com/questions/1379105/the-procedure-entry-point-gettimeout-could-not-be-located-in-the-dll) on Windows 10. I also tried to add a server functionallity for the application by an officially supported patch (tried version 1 and 2) and I get an error `The procedure entry point getTimeout could not be located in the dll`.

I think something went wrong in the installation procedure. I would like to delete the application (normal deinstallation does not help) as if it was not installed before (revert everything that the installation did change e.g. Registry and so forth).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Just delete the application directory.  It is unlikely the application in question uses the registry for anything.  Everything based on my research is handled through configuration files in the directory that contains the executable.

Comment: Multiple questions on what is basically the same problem, makes it nearly impossible, to solve the problem.  You have not provided enough information in either question to determine the reason, reinstalling TORCS, does not clear out your current TORCS configuration.  However, if it's because you simply don't have the required version of Python, reinstalling of Windows will NOT solve your problem.

Comment: All the installer does is express compressed files into a directory contained within Program Files.  The initial installation is not the problem, as I indicated, removing the application directory would remove all of the files connected to TORCS.